# MIPS Snippets to determine clear, set and value of bit k

Tags: assembly, mips

```
  A:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sra $t1, k
    andi $t0, $t0, $t1

  B:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    srl $t0, k
    and $t0, $t0, $t1

  C:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sll $t1, k
    not $t1, $t1
    and $t0, $t0, $t1

  D:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    srl $t1, k
    not $t1, $t1
    and $t0, $t0, $t1

  E:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sll $t1, k
    ori $t0, $t0, $t1
```

1. What code is for clearing bit k in t0?
2. Which code is for setting bit k in t0?
3. Which code is for the value of bit k in t0?

From what I was able to do i got:
1: C
2: D
3: B

Choices A and E are ommited as andi does not add by an immediate and ori has the same issue. Are my answers correct? Either way can you give me a explanation of how each snippets works as I am having confusion with assembly.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Take a MARS simulator, and use the built in environment to try different values, and single-step over instructions to verify your expectations and assumptions. As far as I can tell by just reading the source, it looks like there is probably some typo, because IMO 3. doesn't have a solution (B is close, but the shift would need to be `sll`, not `srl`). For the same reason 2. certainly can't be D. Not even mentioning the `and` can't set bit, only preserve/clear old value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 A:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sra $t1, k
    andi $t0, $t0, $t1
```

A in C would be equivalent to:

```
int tmp1 = 0x00000000 | 0x00000001; // tmp1 = 1;
tmp1 >>= k;
tmp2 &= k;
```

Assuming k is >= 1, any right shift is going to make tmp1 into just all zeros.  If you & with all zeros you get back all zeros, so this basically just clears the value of tmp2, setting it to 0.

```
  B:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    srl $t0, k
    and $t0, $t0, $t1
```

Again we set `tmp1` equal to `0x00000001`.  Then this time we shift it right logically by k digits.  The MSB is 0 so this is actually just equivalent to sra (shift right arithmetic) in this case.  Finally, we and `tmp0` with `tmp1`, which is all zeros, so again all we did was clear the value (so now `$t0`, or as I call it `tmp0`, is just `0x00000000`).

```
  C:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sll $t1, k
    not $t1, $t1
    and $t0, $t0, $t1
```

Same start as before, `tmp1` is set by the `ori` to `0x00000001`.
This time we shift left logically by k, so we get a number of the form `[32 - k many 0s][1 in kth bit][k - 1 many 0s]` in binary.  Then we `not` it, which gives us the inverse (`[32 - k many 1s ][0][k - 1 many 1s]` in binary).  Then we `and` that with `$t0`, clearing `k'th` bit of `t0`.

```
  D:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    srl $t1, k
    not $t1, $t1
    and $t0, $t0, $t1
```

Ok, same as before, `tmp1` is just the number 1 (`0x00000001`).  Then we shift right logically, which so long as k is ≥ 1 means we get `tmp1` to be just zeros.  We not it with itself, so it's all 1s (assuming k was ≥ 1) (`0xffffffff`).  Then we and it with `tmp0`.  Anding something with a bunch of ones won't change it's value, so the value we get back from the `ori` is the value of `tmp1`.  We store that in `$t0`, so I guess this is just a convoluted way of not changing the value of `$t0`.

```
  E:ori $t1, $zero, 1
    sll $t1, k
    ori $t0, $t0, $t1
```

Here `tmp1` is as before set to 1.  `sll` will make us with a 1 in the k'th bit in LSB order, so if we or that mask with `tmp0` we should get `tmp0` with a 1 in that bit (regardless of weather there was or was not a 1 in that bit in `tmp0` in the first place).  So this effectively sets the `kth` LSB to 1 in `tmp0`.

I may have made a mistake somewhere in there; if so feel free to comment or write your own answer accordingly.  I'm deliberately laying out the logic of the code without answering the explicit question because it sounds like a homework question, so I'd like to help you understand the problem without necessarily giving away the solution.  Hope this helps.

Comment: for E: would it set bit k in t0 as  the bits as t1 in 4 bits be: 0001, then shifting left by k of t1, makes 0001 into 0000 if shifted k by 4. then oring 0000 by an arb t0 say 1111 which give 1111, and thus value of t0 = 1111. Am i doing it correctly, I am studying this for my final and the final would be multiple choice so i am trying to use that as an advantage for my coding questions. Do you have any tips that would make solving MIPS problems in MC easier?

Comment: @SudeepBaniya does everything else look right to you?

Comment: `sll 1,k` will create `0b00...00100...00` value, not `0b00..00111..1`. I.e. [only] k-th bit will be set.

Comment: nope... fixed it for you. Maybe use the MARS debugger too? ;) :)

Comment: Fair enough @Ped7g :)

Comment: @Ped7g         sll, a, 2 and set a to be 0111 then by the code 0111 would be 1100 correct?

Comment: @SudeepBaniya `sll, a, 2` is not valid MIPS syntax, and it's not clear to me, what you meant, so I can only guess. But shift-left adds zeroes to the right, not ones. There's rarely instruction to shift left with ones being filled in (Z80 CPU has undocumented one, called `sl1` and I'm not aware of any other CPU). Really, what is blocking you from launching MARS, loading any hello world example, and writing at beginning `li $t0,0x1234` `li $t2,3` (t2 = k) and then the block of operations from your question, then compile + single step over it and watch `t0` and `t1` how they are modified.

Comment: @Ped7g i am currently working from MARS, yes the syntax was jus a general one for me to understand sll, and understood it. Thanks